# Dotted chart or Dashed chart in line chart

Tags: lightningchart

is it possible to make the lineseries as dotted

[image]

If not supported is there any alternative like plotting the line chart on alternate X values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightningChart JS doesn't yet support dotted line styles. We hope to implement dotted line style in future.

Comment: We cannot use null values and keep the line chart blank in between now ?

Comment: @Snekw, can this be done for constant lines though?

Comment: Once support for dotted lines is added, it will also be available for constant lines.